# Search engine for Apache Derby

Tags: solr, full-text-search, derby

I would like use a search engine for my application with Apache Derby database (contatin around 10k rows with text).

For web projects I used an elasticsearch, but it a desktop application. I would like to use an elasticksearch or solr for this app. It possible run elasticsearch or solr for it? It's require many memory or run in other (not application) thread, or have an alternative for derby?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a Lucene-Derby integration as part of this summer's release of Derby: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/DERBY-590

The development is complete; it is in testing. You can get access to it now, and give feedback to the development team about how it works for you.